# How to keep position of button if corresponding textarea is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea and a corresponding button whereby one can expand or compress the textarea. It works so far but I don't like that the button changes its position if the area is expanded. How can I avoid this and keep the button at its initial position (i.e. upper right corner of the textarea and inline with the other elements)?

```js
function resize_textarea(id) {
 var textarea = $(id);
 if (textarea.hasClass('compressed')) {
  textarea.removeClass('compressed').addClass('expanded');
  textarea.attr('rows', 10);
 } else {
  textarea.removeClass('expanded').addClass('compressed');
  textarea.attr('rows', 1);
 }
}
```

```css
.compressed {
  resize: none;
}

.expanded {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select option 1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select option 2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea class="form-control compressed" id="textarea_id" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resize_textarea(textarea_id);">resize</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can give your wrapper class position: relative and for a button position: absolute, then for button eq. set top: 10px; right: 10px; - it's means that you will have your button always in top right corner

Comment: use this css rule `input-group-btn { vertical-align: top; }` (you might need to add a selector before if you want to restrict to this specific button group or else all will be affected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you just need to add `vertical-align: top` to the `span` which holds the button.

Note that you'll need to ensure the rule has high enough specificity yo override the existing `vertical-align` setting. You can do that by adding multiple class selectors to it. Using `!important` should be avoided where at all possible.

Also note that your JS code can be tidied up by using unobtrusive event handlers and the `toggleClass()` method. Try this:

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $('#textarea_id').toggleClass('compressed').attr('rows', function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('compressed') ? 1 : 10;
  });
});
```

```css
textarea.form-control {
  resize: none;
}

.compressed {
  resize: none;
}

.expanded {
  resize: none;
}

.input-group-btn.top-button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select option 1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select option 2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea class="form-control compressed" id="textarea_id" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
      <span class="input-group-btn top-button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary expand">resize</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Although all given answers so far aren't wrong I prefer yours. Because I'll have more than one row so it's easier to add a class instead of working with ids (see Connum's answer). Your JS hint is good, but doing so the textarea will be resizable if it is expanded.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can fix the resizable problem by adding `resize: false` to the `textarea` in CSS. I updated the answer to show you exactly how

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `vertical-align: top` to the span around the button in order to have it stay in the top right corner of the textarea. This will also have your resize button aligned to the "add" button next to it.

```js
function resize_textarea(id) {
 var textarea = $(id);
 if (textarea.hasClass('compressed')) {
  textarea.removeClass('compressed').addClass('expanded');
  textarea.attr('rows', 10);
 } else {
  textarea.removeClass('expanded').addClass('compressed');
  textarea.attr('rows', 1);
 }
}
```

```css
.compressed {
  resize: none;
}

.expanded {
  resize: none;
}

#textarea_id + .input-group-btn {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select option 1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select option 2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea class="form-control compressed" id="textarea_id" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resize_textarea(textarea_id);">resize</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```